# Android 4 slows down over year without reason

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lg

I have LG-P760 with Android 4.0.4, not rooted.

I have about 500MB free space on phone and for last year I haven't really install much apps and so on. Despite that, my Android started to work slower, than slower and now it's ultra-slow.

I don't recall installing anything, using it extensively, mess with rooting or anything like that.

But even simple loading web browser or backing too home screen to see the pinned applications takes enormous amount of time now.

I've already tried clearing cache of applications and restarting phone several times during last month.

What may cause such behavior and how to get back to normal?
I know one year ago this phone with virtually the same set of applications and amount of stored pictures/music/etc. was capable of running very smoothly.
It looks almost as it was programmed to get slow after year ;)

Comment: No one else has said it yet, but you probably knew it was coming anyway. Back everything up and do a factory reset.

Comment: Factory reset won't help too much. The thing is that phone is run over by time, so the solution would be buying a new phone

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје What do you understand under "run over by time"? It's piece of hardware, with processor, memory etc. and I wasn't using it extensively. I know friends who use their older phones more and don't have such problems after even few years. I would consider it unacceptable to "run over time" that way for PC/tablet/notebook or any other similar hardware and same should go for phones - after all it's not made out of bambus (at least I hope so).

Comment: I mean that is old device now since it have 4.0.4 android, everything older than kit-kat is normal to be laggy. What do you expect from dual core device from 2012?

Comment: From device from 2012 I expect approx. to works the same it was working in 2012 if the conditions are the same - it has the same messanging app, disc, processor and same things to do - no new apps installed. Comparing e.g. Windows and Android OS. I still have 20yo laptop with Windows XP now on it. And it works virtually the same way it was years ago. If there were none changes in software and hardware is ok, why should few years affect it that much? I consider it very low-quality solution either in case of harware or software - I will try factory reset to determine if it's OS fault or not.

Comment: @EthanZ Can you make answer out of your question? Unfortunatelly, factory reset was the only choice here and it did helped (mostly).

Comment: It's not going to work same as when you bought it because of simple reason that software is upgradeing and getting better (or worse) but it requires better technology and more resources all things are developing but your hardware stays the same that is why phones/pc's start to lag and such. In smartphones case 2012 is old. If your 20 yrs laptop works same as first day than either it was crap even than or you're lying because it's not possible even if you use laptop for just to turn it off and on.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје It would be true if I would update/upgrade any software. Software is virtually the same as it was year ago. And please stop making personal trips calling me liar just because what I wrote does not goes with your view on things. And yes, there's nothing strange with hardware/software working as they should for more then 5-10 years if you work with same set of apps - at least for good hardware/software. For me, if after not even 5 years hardware stays the same and software is the same and it makes hardware to lag on even simplest operations - software is poorly written.

Comment: You are wrong longest time that smarphones can be used normally is 4 years max only in flagship case in non-flagship that time is shorter

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I am not interested into arguing further with you on that topic. And if I would, I think I should suggest chat, not comment section. Just for note, the phone was produced in 2012 but I bought it from company about 2 years ago and it was boxed (not unwrapped or used earlier).

Comment: Whatever. Naah, arguing online is pointless, sorry for bad words, that was just my opinion and look on some things. Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a factory reset. After a while, things get gunked up with tons of unnecessary files that aren't always deleted and a lot of other stuff.

However, your phone will always slow down over time because apps become more demanding as technology progresses. There isn't much that can be done about this.

Comment: Unfortunately that was the case. I consider it a bit as low quality of software (Android), not to run stable and need to be reset after year or two. Thank you for suggesting the factory reset - after it everything works almost the same as it was year ago - there is an lag, but definitely not as ridiculous as before (waiting 20 seconds to see incomed sms). For other people facing same problem: remember to backup your data, images, smses and contacts before factory reset :)